# backslash escaped string with accented letters to ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a string that represents a dict. The format of the string includes characters like "\x7B" (sorry I'm not sure what to call this - backslash encoding?) It also contains accented characters in the form "\u00fa" (again, sorry, I'm not sure what this is called). I would like to:

1. Change all "\x7B" style characters to their corresponding "normal" characters, here it would be "{"
2. Change all "\u00fa" style characters to corresponding ascii characters (i.e. no accent), here "\u00fa" becomes "ú" and so would be "u".

It's difficult to tell whats going on behind the scenes as when I print these strings it automatically converts the "\x7B" style characters to their "normal" equivalents.

For example, I would like to be able to convert `'\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x22Ra\x5Cu00fal\x22\x7D'` to `'{"h":"Raul"}'`

Side note:
How would I be able to view `'\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x22Ra\x5Cu00fal\x22\x7D'` as `'\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x22Ra\x5Cu00fal\x22\x7D'` rather than `'{"h":"Ra\\u00fal"}'`?

Also, if you could include the proper names of each of the string formats (encodings?) so I could update the question name to make it more suitable for future reference, that'd be great.

Comment: The terminology you're looking for is backslash *escaping*. And Python, as you've seen, takes care of interpreting the escapes for you, unless you're reading from a data source that actually contains the backslash characters themselves.

Comment: As for stripping away the accent characters, I don't know Python, but I can put the answer into words: the trick is to create a lookup for which character translates to which other character. Use characters with a character code less than 0x80 (128) directly, use the character code of each character 0x80 and above as an index into that lookup.

Comment: Does the string start with ``\``, `x`, `7`, `B`, or does it start with the single character *represented* by `\x7B`?

Comment: Do you want to try using `chr()' to turn it into the ascii character of the hex value?

Comment: "Reading from a data source that actually contains the backslash characters themselves", in which case Python escape syntax might not be relevant at all. For example, it could be JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @chepner It starts with `\ `, `x`, `7`, `B`

Comment: @TomBlodget yes I think it may be JavaScript syntax as it is scraped from source HTML of a web page

Comment: @Sockey That conflicts with the fact that you selected an answer where `s` starts with the single byte `\x7b`, not the character ``\``. Is `ord(s[0])` 123 or 92?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json.loads` to convert the encoded string to dict and then normalize it and finally convert it to equivalent ascii

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> s = '\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x22Ra\x5Cu00fal\x22\x7D'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', str(json.loads(s))).encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
"{'h': 'Raul'}"
```

Comment: '\x7B' is valid JavaScript but not valid JSON.